# Excel VBA - remove weekends from automatic timesheet print

Tags: excel, vba, printing, dateadd

I slightly amended some code I found online.

Purpose:

Click on a 'Print with Dates' button, then enter start date, and have Excel automatically generate/print a months worth of timesheets (much better than the previous spreadsheet having 6 weeks of pages to print, and you had to edit every date manually).

Issues:

- It prints weekends, which wastes paper. Is there a way it can refer to a list of dates (weekends, public holidays), and not generate those for printing?
- You'll see the date format is m/d/yyyy in the code, which strangely prints as dd/mm/yyyy (which is what I wanted). When the code was dd/mm/yyyy it was printing correctly (20/03/2019), but if it goes to the following month it was switching to American format m/d/yyyy (04/20/2019). I know it doesn't seem to make sense, but having it as m/d/yyyy actually prints as dd/mm/yyyy across any start/end dates. I'd like to know why, and also have dd/mm/yyyy in the code correctly printing across any date range.

CODE:

```
Sub PrintSheet()
    Dim s As String
    Dim d As Date
    s = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the start date")
    If Not IsDate(s) Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect date", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For d = CDate(s) To DateAdd("m", 1, CDate(s)) - 1
        Range("F2").Value = Format(d, "dddd")
        Range("I2").Value = "" & Format(d, "m/d/yyyy")
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    Next d
End Sub
```

Cheers in advance :)

Comment: Gary, VBA has some Constants you can use to check for Weekends (**vbweekend**, etc.) Go to the Object Explorer (F2) and search for them there.

Comment: Thanks J, I looked for VBweekend but was not available. VBDayOfWeek is in the list. Excel 2013 I'm afraid. I should have mentioned that in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the weekday function. It returns a number from 1 to 7. You can filter for 1-5 only for weekdays.

```
Sub PrintSheet()
    Dim s As String
    Dim d As Date
    s = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the start date")
    If Not IsDate(s) Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect date", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For d = CDate(s) To DateAdd("m", 1, CDate(s)) - 1
        If Weekday(d, vbMonday) < 6 Then
        Range("F2").Value = Format(d, "dddd")
        Range("I2").Value = "" & Format(d, "m/d/yyyy")
        'MsgBox ("printing ") 'for testing
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut
        End If
    Next d
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Baris, that works much better in most cases.

I tested a number of start dates, and all did the weekdays except when I started on 15/03/2019, which skipped all weekends but included Sunday 14/04/2019.

Comment: Including Sunday 14/04/2019 possibly as it is the last day of that month printout, and that overrides the weekend ignore. 

This is much better though. Will test at printing from other Fridays (here in Australia), and see if it is a constant when finishing on a Sunday.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it! Remember the `weekday` function goes off of the machines settings. So if you plan to give this out to other regions using different time settings, then will be different.

Comment: If I enter any Friday as the start date, it always ends on the Sunday (30 days later, so I guess 1 month in excel terms is 30 days) and prints the Sunday.

I can live with that, and just not print the last day on the printer. Thanks again :)

Comment: It goes through all days, including weekdays and weekend, but it shouldn't print the Sunday. It will just skip those. Comment out the `ActiveSheet.PrintOut` and uncomment the MsgBox line, and you should see that it will not print the last page if it's a Saturday or Sunday.

Comment: Thanks Baris, commented/uncommented as you said. Didn't really make any difference to the result. I just had to press 'OK' on the 'Printing' button a lot to cycle through all the days it was sending.

Is there a way to upload an excel file to this post? I saw there was a help link on how to attach on the upper right, on a page, but it wasn't an active link (I'm using Chrome).

Comment: Ok - I edited the code a little. I moved the if statement 2 lines up. Now it shouldn't show the page as well if it's a weekend day. Can you try again?

Comment: Genius! Perfect!

It ended on a Friday now :) Wish I could upload this so others can benefit.

Comment: I found the site where the original code is from, so wanted to give credit to HansV: 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/to-stamp-consecutive-date-on-every-page/c62c8dd5-52d2-455e-ac57-c2227552634e